# Is there anyway to bypass filter that blocks TOR users on a certain website?

Tags: tor, bypass

Well the questions sums it up I think. Is there anyway to bypass filter that blocks TOR users on a certain website?

Comment: tor is probably blocked due to abuse. Block evasion may not be the smartest thing to do in that case

Answer (score 2):

TOR filters typically block known (and popular) TOR exit nodes. In most cases they would only be able to block the largest and most used exit nodes.

I'd suggest using the unpopular/small (and frequently slow) exit nodes.

If that doesn't help, just use one of the open HTTP proxies on top of TOR, however if a website blocks TOR nodes, they very well may block known HTTP proxies. You'll need to scour IRC and the underweb for fresh proxies.